# Django/Nginx DisallowedHost header error

Tags: python, django, nginx, dns

There are several of these threads, but none of them have an answer to my problem.  I have a server hosting a website that is working perfectly if you direct there via the ip address, however I bought a dns, and I am trying to redirect the dns to the ip.  I am using django 1.11.4 (the current pip install version).  After setting up all of my DNS servers I can ping the server, but if I go to a browser and type in my dns I receive this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET

Request URL: http://thefelpub.com/

Django Version: 1.11.4
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pub')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  244.             response = middleware_method(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  57.         host = request.get_host()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py" in get_host
  113.             raise DisallowedHost(msg)

Exception Type: DisallowedHost at /
Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'thefelpub.com'. You may need to add u'thefelpub.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I have added my dns to the ALLOWED_HOSTS=[] list, but no matter how many variations of the dns I try (including '*') I get the same error every time I try to get there.

Comment: did you restart django after add `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'] `?

Comment: Yes, I restart nginx after every time I tried to change ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: You restart gunicorn not nginx for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `ALLOWED_HOSTs = ['45.55.54.110', 'www.thefelpub.com', 'thefelpub.com']`, Save the settings.py file and then restart gunicorn, `service gunicorn restart` to restart Django.

Comment: I haven't encrypted it yet since I can't eve get the DNS to point to it.  That's the next task and this is holding me back.  I added
`server_name example.com www.example.com;`
to and changed example to my server name, but now if I type thefelpub.com I get the nginx welcome page, and www.thefelpub.com gives me the same error I had before.  The IP is still working correctly.

Comment: So the issue is the domain name pointing to the server? How have you configured the dns settings? You are using which hosting company?

Comment: I am using namecheap pointing to digital cloud.  Namecheap is pretty poorly documented, but from digital cloud I was told to have the nameserver set to custom and point them to digital cloud's  ns1.digitalocean.com,  ns2.digitalocean.com, and n3.digitalocean.com.

Digital Cloud has an 'A' that points thefelpub.com to the ip, a CNAME that nicknames to thefelpub.com, and the three NS that are pre-built when you create the record.

Comment: You have added  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ipaddress','thefelpub.com','www.thefelpub.com'] in your settings.py and restarted gunicorn? You need to restart gunicorn for any changes made to the .py files

Comment: Yes.  `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['thefelpub.com', 'www.thefelpub.com']` is in there right now, and I had `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['thefelpub.com', 'www.thefelpub.com']` and restarted nginx.  `service nginx stop` then `service nginx start` several times. `service nginx restart` too.

Comment: Restart gunicorn for .py file changes to take effect. `service gunicorn restart` Not service nginx restart

Comment: Thank you for that, but after doing `service gunicorn restart` I still have thefelpub.com showing me the welcome to nginx page and www.thefelpub.com showing me the Disallowed Host page :(

Comment: Am getting these are the settings in your file directly from running the url ALLOWED_HOSTS
['127.0.0.1', '::1', '45.55.54.110', 'fe80::e875:e9ff:fe22:b96f%eth0']. Do you see where the problem is? Your django_project.settings is showing something else for the ALLOWED_HOST

Comment: That is why only 45.55.54.110 is working and not the domain names. They are not included in the settings.py. Are you saving the changes after updating the ALLOWED_HOSTS???

Comment: Later in settings.py there is `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()` which I think is causing the problem, but I tried adding the other urls in like this `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ip_addresses(), 'www.thefelpub.com', 'thefelpub.com']` the best I could tell `ip_addresses()` gathers a list that contain my ip address and adds 127.0.0.1, and :1.  Also, yes I am saving the settings.py file after every change, and now restarting gunicron now.

Comment: Just use without the ip_addresses(), that is ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['45.55.54.110', 'www.thefelpub.com', 'thefelpub.com'], save file and restart gunicorn.

Comment: Sorry stack overflow logged me out while I was trying to praise you!  Thank you @deaspo, I had to comment out the second `ALLOWED_HOSTS` that contained `ip_addresses()`.  Since it is a constant, and the function `ip_addresses()` was probably called first causing it to be stored in a non-changeable format (as constants are expected to behave), so the first one was just never being executed despite it being first in the program.
I am not sure why Django formatted the file that way, but one could only assume that's for dev purposes while hosting locally, and they just assume you'll fix it later.

Comment: Editing my answer to reflect what helped you solve the issue. If you need help setting up the SSL you can always holla. Don't forget to mark it as the answer @baneofalltrades

Answer (score 1):

Has mentioned in the error message, you certainly need to add "thefelpub.com" in [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['thefelpub.com']
```

or, not recommended:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]
```

Comment: In addition you need to serve the same domain name in the nginx available sites to adding the given answer to your seettings.py

Comment: I've tried:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['thefelpub.com']

I've also tried:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

Neither have worked.  Later in the code there is:
     ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()

and I am not quite sure if that is causing any problems, or not (it was put there by Django)

Comment: @deaspo I've only been doing this for about 24 hours now, so I am quite the noob still.  How do I serve the domain name in nginx?

Comment: Do you need more explanation? I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.